# SharpSSH's Scp object can't copy files bigger than 2GB

Tags: c#, .net, scp, sharpssh

Whenever I try to copy a file that's bigger than 2GB, I get an array index out of bounds exception in the Get method:

```
Scp myScp = new Scp("remotehost", "joe", "mypassword");
myScp.OnTransferProgress += new FileTransferEvent(scpProg);
myScp.Connect(22);
myScp.Get("/home/joe/bigfile.bin", "/tmp/bigfile.bin");
myScp.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...which I solved by patching SharpSSH replacing int with Int64 in strategic places. [Here's the patch](http://users.vialink.com.br/jcastro/SharpSSH-bigfiles.patch).

Comment: I'm starting to add some stuff that I needed to SharpSSH over at https://bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/sharpssh and I am going to try and include your patch.

Comment: Please tell me you're making it run in .NET 4.0! I get some weird errors in host resolution when I compile Tamir's code under .NET 4. It only works up to .NET 3.5.

Comment: It's definitely not the smoothest experience and the exception handling is awful, but at least it's a starting point!